# How to conditionally drop a constraint in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to query for a specific constraint, and if it exists, drop it, otherwise I want to do nothing and move on. I am attempting to do so with the following code:

```
SHOW CONSTRAINTS YIELD name, labelsOrTypes, properties
WHERE labelsOrTypes = ["NodeLabel"] AND properties = ["targetProperty"]
WITH name
CALL apoc.when(
    name IS NOT NULL,
    'DROP CONSTRAINT name',
    '',
    {name: name}
) YIELD value;
```

This gives an error `Invalid input 'WITH'`. Removing the `WITH` gives `Invalid input 'CALL'`. Returning the `name` property gives the same error.

Neo4J lists in their documentation that "One of the output columns from SHOW CONSTRAINTS is the name of the constraint. This can be used to drop the constraint with the DROP CONSTRAINT command." Removing the APOC call and doing the following also results in an error:

```
SHOW CONSTRAINTS YIELD name, labelsOrTypes, properties
WHERE labelsOrTypes = ["PublicToken"] AND properties = ["token"]
DROP CONSTRAINT name
```

This tells me `Invalid input 'd'`, so it seems you can't use `DROP CONSTRAINT` immediately after showing constraints. What am I missing? Is this command just not able to be used in a script and has to be used manually?

Comment: you cannot do drop constraint conditionally in cypher. Cypher syntax does not allow it. You can use Python or Javascript or GO to write a code for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `SHOW CONSTRAINTS` is a command, and we can't use it as a subquery or pipeline its output, along with other Cypher clauses, to achieve some functionality.

This [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/syntax/#administration-constraints-syntax-list) gives the complete syntax for `SHOW CONSTRAINTS`, as you can see `WITH` is not supported. For the command, `YIELD` acts as `RETURN`, if no return statement is present. So, you will have to run `DROP CONSTRAINT`, manually after your constraints are listed,

Comment: Is there any way to do this in a script? Or if you want to drop constraints conditionally, does it always have to be done manually?

Comment: not directly via a query, but you can write short script which uses neo4j http api https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/